# VBO vs display list vs VA

Tags: opengl, vbo, displaylist

I have a list of vertices that I plan to mutate and was hoping to get a little clarification on the differences among a VBO, display list, & VA -- I am trying to speed up the rendering within my application.  Are VBOs and Display lists not options because I am not rendering static geometry?

Answer (score 2):

Well, using anything *other* than VBOs (i.e., client-side memory pointers and/or display lists) isn't an option in Core contexts.

For dynamic data you can specify `GL_STREAM_DRAW`/`GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` in your `glBufferData()` call's `usage` parameter and hope your GL implementation gets the hint.